# How can I produce valid JSON using the toJSON method from rjson/RJSONIO in R?

Tags: r

given the following R code:

```
library(rjson)
x <- c(3:5)
toJSON(x)
```

it produces:

```
[1] "[3,4,5]"
```

when I am expecting something like:

```
"[3,4,5]"
```

I am a new to R, I guess this is something easy to do, but I had have no luck finding a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that [1] is just the R Console's output indicating that "[3,4,5]" is the first element in that vector. The actual result stored is in fact "[3,4,5]". Try this:

```
cat(toJSON(x))
```

So, for instance, if you stored the JSON result in a new variable, and passed it on to something else, the '[1]' doesn't ride along, just the part you want. It's only for display purposes in the console.

Comment: I think @joran has nailed it. If you need to convince yourself, try executing `"[3,4,5]" == toJSON(x)`

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I needed. I am using R(Apache) so I needed a clean output.